# How to pass id, name & value of a div tag to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I am trying to pass value stored inside a div tag to a javascript function based on the onchange property of a drop down menu in HTML.

But nothing is being passed. Undefined error is shown.

Here my code:

Suppose `$temp_c` has a value 30.

```
<span id="temperature_div"><?php echo $temp_c; ?></span>

<label for="ddl_temptype"></label>
<select id="ddl_temptype" name="ddl_temptype" onchange="choose_temperature(this.value,temperature_div.value,temperature_div.name); ">
    <option value="celcius" selected>°C</option>
    <option value="farenheit">°F</option>
</select>
```

And JavaScript

```js
function choose_temperature(conv, value, name) {
    alert(conv);
    alert(value);
    alert(name);
}
```

Where did I go wrong??

Comment: What is 'name' refers to?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: What kind of "Undefined" error?

Comment: I see tag `javascript` so select the div by `getElementById` and then get the values you want to pass.

Comment: I would prefer using `data-attributes` over this approach!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript you can't just use `temperature_div` as a variable and assume it will be the object with id `temperature_div`. There are functions for fetching elements from the DOM. In plain JavaScript: `document.getElementById('temperature_div')`  will return the element. If you're using JQuery, then `$('#temperature_div')` will do a similar thing.

Edit:

Try this function:

```
function choose_temperature(conv) {
    alert(conv);
    var element = document.getElementById('temperature_div');
    alert(element.innerHTML);
    alert(element.attributes["name"].value);
}
```

Called by: `choose_temperature(this.value);`

Edit: Changed to use `innerHTML` and `attributes["name"].value` instead of `value` and `name`. I'm assuming that these are what are wanted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have used the parameter 'value' which I think is a key word and better not to use. 
and I am assuming you are referring to the 'name' html attribute in the 'temperature_div', which you have not defined. I am putting a name attribute just for the sake of understanding.

```
<html>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    function choose_temperature(conv, t_value, name) 
            {
                alert(conv);
                var div = document.getElementById("temperature_div");
                alert(div.innerHTML);
                alert(div.getAttribute("name"));
            }
    </script>
```

```
<label for="ddl_temptype"></label>
<select id="ddl_temptype" name="ddl_temptype" onchange="choose_temperature(this.value); ">
    <option value="celcius" selected>°C</option>
    <option value="farenheit">°F</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `getElementById()` in javascript

```
<span id="temperature_div"><?php echo $temp_c; ?></span>

    <label for="ddl_temptype"></label>
    <select id="ddl_temptype" name="ddl_temptype" onchange="choose_temperature(); ">
  <option value="celcius" selected> °C</option>
 <option value="farenheit"> °F</option>
  </select>


function choose_temperature()
{
    var value=document.getElementById('temperature_div').innerHTML; //to get html inside span
     var conv=document.getElementById('ddl_temptype').value;

    alert(conv);
    alert(value);

}
```

Comment: No. This is not passing in, your function is brittle and does not answer the requirements in the question.

Comment: @SecondRikudo why? he just want to get the values of the div? right?

Comment: Which div? The ides is to pass the value into the function. Not to mention that `span`s don't have the `.value` property.

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery instead, it is easier.

Get value inside a div as: $('#temperature_div').html()  Or  $('#temperature_div').text()

You can write onchange for a select box as:

```
$(document).on('change', '#ddl_temptype', function() {

  // Write your function here
  var div_value = $('#temperature_div').html();
  var select_val = $(this).val();


 alert(div_value);

});
```

Or like this

```
$('#some_id').on('change', function() {

   // Write your function here
      var div_value = $('#temperature_div').html();
      var select_val = $(this).val();


     alert(div_value);
});
```

Comment: JQuery is certainly much easier to use for things like this that are more complex, and would be a good thing to learn for doing this in general. However, I'd say that something as simple as this doesn't particularly benefit from its use.